# How to check what is OS of self hosted agent?

Tags: azure-devops, agent, self-hosting, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

i am new to Azure and having basic question.
How do we know self hosted agent is windows machine or mac or Linux? while configuring this, we are not choosing what should be the OS of my agent. In Microsoft hosted agent where we have dropdown list to see and choose. But in self hosted agent configuration, we will choose only from which machine (windows/MaC/Linux) we are going to configure agent but not what agent OS is.
Please help

Comment: you are installing the self-hosted agents yourself... so you should know?! If you want your users to know, just add the OS to the name of your agents

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just to clarify, my need is windows OS but while configuring i dont see an option to choose which OS .

Comment: you dont need to configure. If you need different OS for your private agents, you will just set up different private agent pools. Picking the right pool for the right build job is your responsibility

Answer (score 0):

You can print out the Agent OS within your job

```
steps:
- script: |
    echo Agent OS is: $AGENT_OS
  displayName: Agent OS
  env:
    AGENT_OS: $(agent.os)
```

[image]